# Is "Type" deprecated in Elasticsearch 6?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm pretty confused.

Here it says that it is deprecated and you could only use one type per index:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/removal-of-types.html

But when i try to create 2 documents in 2 different types in the same index, Elasticsearch `6.2.2` doesn't complain:

`PUT http://IP:9200/blogs/post/1`
`PUT http://IP:9200/blogs_v2/post/1`

Could somebody please clarify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Types are not completely removed, but as an advice for the future change, one can only save one type pro index.

From the link that you posted:

> Elasticsearch 6.x
>   
> - Indices created in 6.x only allow a single-type per index. Any name can be used for the type, but ..

So you have an index named **blogs** with one type post and an index **blogs_v2** with a type post. These are two different indexes, containing one type each. Therefore legal

Comment: Well this is awkward, my example was really a bad one, didn't notice haha. Sorry i'm an Elasticsearch beginner. Thanks!

Comment: „Mapping types will be completely removed in Elasticsearch 7.0.0.“ - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/removal-of-types.html